# How to upload video to facebook have link learn more

Tags: facebook, video, web

How to upload video to facebook have link Learn More like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a Call to Action Button to Your Facebook Video. Follow the following steps to add it in your facebook videos.

[Click here](http://www.shortstack.com/how-to-add-a-call-to-action-button-to-your-facebook-video/)

Click the above link to know the steps.

Hope you got your answers.